# Upload 1 missing dSYM required to process 1 crash

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

In Firebase Crashlytics Dashboard for my iOS App, I am getting this warning "Upload 1 missing dSYM required to process 1 crash" for the Live Version. So I downloaded the DSYM files from the App store. But I am still getting the same warning. So I need some more clarification How does DSYM file for a particular UUID, accessed by App Store and in my case it surely fails to do so. So what could be the reason.

Comment: Did you had this one fixed? I also uploaded a new version at the begining of August, replacing the SDK with the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK and haven't been able to upload the dSYM succesfully. Another app of mine is working fine though

Comment: I was able to upload the file, but 1 particular DSYM file was still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Firebaser here - have you tried uploading the dSYM file in the Firebase console as specified [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#upload-dsyms)? If you're getting an error with the upload, make sure you've included the correct identifying Google Services file. If the upload is successful, you may be trying to upload the wrong dSYM:

1. Try getting the dSYM from your local Xcode Archives rather than the App Store, if that's an option, and uploading that
2. Try finding a dSYM by a particular UUID with the method [laid out here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#expandable-2).
3. You can always check the UUID of a particular dSYM by using `shasum /path/to/file.dsym`. It if matches the one in the Firebase console, that's the one you should upload.

If you can't get it working after all of that, file a case with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) and they'll be able to dig in further.

Comment: I have tried all above steps, but still no luck. It still shows 1 DSYM file required.